# How to make a custom UITabBarController?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a project and I would like to implement a custom UITabBarController similar to [image: Pinterest show here]. How can I approach this to make something similar? Does the UITabBarController class support this much customization or should I create it in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you could achieve your desired behavior with all `UITabBarController, UIKit and SwiftUI`.

[image: Floating Button]
Caption: Image of `Floating Button`

**BUT**,
Assuming your design is similar to the one you provided, the design seems more like a `Floating Button`. In addition, in iOS development, using UI components to its purpose is highly encouraged. And any iOS developer would say the same thing to discourage deviating from the UI component's main purpose. If you override `UITabBarController` to achieve the behavior of a `Floating Button`, then you are not following proper iOS guidelines.

**SO** I highly encourage you to create it using traditional `UIKit/SwiftUI` components.

**PS**: If you need some starter tutorials, here are some I recommend

- [SwiftUI version](https://github.com/exyte/FloatingButton)
- [UIKit version](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@andrixyz/creating-floating-action-button-in-ios-development-like-in-path-app)